How to prevent Windows asking for a proxy when setting up Windows
Our environment has  settings so that users do not need to use a proxy. We want to stop automatically asking for a proxy in Windows setting (security).
I've searched all over the console and MMC, but can't find the relevant settings. Is there a relevant Registry Key?

Asking where and how – do you have a screenshot? I've never seen such a prompt in regular Windows setup processes (and in general, there's nothing special about not needing a proxy), so I'm guessing this was something added locally in the first place?
